# Blender creates cloud at specular areas

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting

[image: The node setup]I have been working on a plastic material for a while now.
And even though I seem to be close to what what I want, everytime I render,blender shows me clouds instead of reflectivity.Can anyone please help me out?
This is quite urgent please.
And it even doesn't matter if I change the seed  or the render samples,those clouds still appear no matter what.
Thank you[image]

Comment: You should probably post a screenshot of the material nodes, what are the lights/render settings too?

Comment: I have Sir.. Just now.And I haven't turned on the denoising . Even when I did, it didn't make much of a difference.